# Combinatorics coloring question (n-level honeycomb with its center hexagon removed & the number of ways hexagon trex can cover it is to be found)

Tags: combinatorics

Let *n* be a positive integer

an *n-level honeycomb* is a plane region covered with regular hexagons of side-length 1 connected along edges, such that the centres of the boundary hexagons are lined up along a regular hexagon of side length *n√3*

the diagram shows a 2-level honeycomb from which the central hexagon has been removed

a *trex* is a sequence of 3 hexagons with collinear centres such that the middle hexagon shares an edge with each of its neighbours in the trex

an *n*-level honeycomb from which the central size-1 hexagon has been removed is to be completely covered y trexes without any overlaps

find all possible values of *n* for which this is possible

[image]

if i understood the question correctly i need to find the all possible values of n where the n-level honeycomb can be covered by trexes

I calculated that for an addition of each level the number of hexagons(minus the centre) in total would be n*2 + n, where n is the number of hexagons in the last one level
now i tried first 5 levels and obviously they can be covered by trexes of 3 hexagons

so is the total number of possible values of n infinite or have i got the question wrong

also i cannot understand the purpose of the side length. Either way i think that the possible number of values of n-level would be infinite as the number of hexagons in any n-level honeycomb would be a multiple of 3 so it can be covered by trexes

however i have no idea how to find the number of possible ways of arranging those trex, infact i think its not even possible to determine it using the usual coloring method

> this is my very first post so please bear my bad presentation
> i did my best and i will certainly improve it in my next post

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Please make clear whether you want a formula for the _number_ of trex-tilings as function of $n$ (as your last paragraph suggests) or just a characterisation of those $n$ for which it is possible at all, as seems to have been the question you were asked (this would be just finding those $n$ for which the formula has a nonzero value, which might be a lot easier than actually finding the formula).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By construction it looks like $n \equiv 0,2 \pmod{3}$ works. It is easy to construct a tiling for the honeycomb shown, and then extend it to a third level. Looks like you should be able to fill the outer 3 layers and apply induction for the larger cases. If you look at these, it would probably become apparent quickly whether $n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ is doable for larger n.

Finding the number of tilings as a function of n looks tough.